# Translate NetBIOS Frames to NetBIOS over TCP/IP

Tags: debian, networking, netbios

We own an old CNC milling machine with a NUM control unit. It's connected to a Windows NT PC over Ethernet, they communicate via [NetBIOS Frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_Frames). We now want to modernise the PC and can run the control software on modern Windows systems, but NBF is only supported up to Windows 7.

We've been thinking to use a small linux system (e.g. a Raspberry) to "translate" the NetBIOS Frames to TCP/IP encapsulated packets to make sure the NUM controller can talk to more modern systems. As we'll likely only need the name- and datagram services, we should be fine with UDP packets and without session handling.

Alternatively we could run the name server and fileserver on the linux machine and make sure to sync the files another way.

Is it possible to do what we're looking for on linux and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain NetBIOS (or NetBEUI as it is sometimes referred to in Windows) has never been supported by Samba, and since the worldwide WannaCry ransomware cyberattack of May 2017, even NetBIOS over TCP/IP is being deprecated in an accelerated schedule along with SMBv1.

There are [some references to NetBEUI support patches](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netbeui) for ancient kernels (versions 2.0.36 .. 2.4.34.1) and for Samba version 2.2.8. I would think all of this is too old to be useful.

I would recommend you to virtualize the Windows NT PC, so that you will be able to run the VM on modern hardware.